# How to make the Activiti workflow in Activiti Explorer call the outer Java program

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

I installed the Activity Explorer, and H2 standalone server. Everything works fine, as I see: I can start a workflow, claim and complete user tasks, but that's not enough. I need the workflow to call external services, suppose via REST. But I have no idea how to deploy the code to do that.
Is that possible using javascript (or groovy) in the workflow xml, or is there any way to inject Java code, or even deploy Java module?
I am totally confused about the technology, any example could help.

Comment: From the docs it seems to be possible to call wide range of external services, e.g. http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnJavaServiceTask

Comment: Yes, but how to add the class to classpath?

Comment: Google: `site:forums.activiti.org classpath` points to e.g. http://forums.activiti.org/content/classnotfoundexception-when-trying-implement-service-task. I don't know if that is the answer but overall Activiti Forums seems to be active and may be more useful then Stack Overflow. BTW: your question is broad, unclear, no code shown and as such it does not match the Stack Overflow on-topic Q&A format (http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Also have a look at Eclipse Stardust (http://www.eclipse.org/stardust/) it has easy to use task types to connect to external service (e.g. via REST) without having to deploy any code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sorry for this type of question derived from my lack of experience...
Anyway, I would like to answer it.
One should wright a class implementing JavaDelegate, and pute desirable code inside the execute(..) method, compile, export as jar and put the jar in WEB-INF/lib.
In the .bpmn diagram which is pure xml, Service Task node there should have a reference to that class.
I think there enough key words to have a clue how to search details, so that's all for now.

Comment: I have same problem. can you help me in detail? thanks

Comment: @hadiJZ You should probably follow the documentation and do search by keywords I gave in my answer as I didn't do much Activiti, that was an occasional research.